# How to store only time in CoreData without date component using UIDatePicker in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsdate, uidatepicker

I am using `UIDatePicker` in my app to select time without date and storing its value in `CoreData`. But date value also gets stored if I use `datePicked.date` (`datePicked` is `UIDatePicker`) in my code. I know I can use `NSDateFormatter` to store `HH:mm a` format but I don't want to store string in my data model. Even if I store `dateFromString` function to store time in required format the default date is added along with time. Please tell me how can I store only time without date. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Save it as NSDate and when you want to retrieve it use NSDateFormater with a format "HH:mm a" to get timeString. You can also use NSDateCoponents to split hours, minutes etc from NSDate object.

Comment: can you save timeIntervalSince1970 instead of date object or you even do not want to save time interval too ?

Comment: Set the date part always to a fixed value, i.e. 2000-01-01 so it won't mess up your sorting or comparison.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions guys. I am aware of all the options suggested here. But I am really surprised to know that we can't store only time and not date as NSDate in data model. There should be some way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated**
You can save transformable values in Core Data. Like this class:

```
class Time: NSValueTransformer {
let hour: Int
let minute: Int
let second: Int

override init() { // only sample code
    hour = 0
    minute = 0
    second = 0
}

override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
    return NSNumber.self
}

override func reverseTransformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    guard let number = value as? NSNumber else {
        return nil
    }
    return Time() // you should init Time from the number
}

override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    let number = hour * 60 * 60 + minute * 60 + second
    return number
}

override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

You should add transformable attribute like this:
[image]
And you will get this in model file:

```
extension Entity {

    @NSManaged var time: Time? // modify it to Time manually

}
```

And now, you can save `Time` to managed object.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I store these values as a single time value in CoreData model?

Comment: @RajaRupinderSingh Updated my answer.

Comment: As I can see your approach the time is being converted into seconds before getting saved to data model. However,  I also need to fire a local notification based on time. So I also need Am/Pm parameters to fire notification correctly. Is it possible to store Am/Pm value with time or will I have to store it as string and then make a comparison with the stored value of string?

Comment: @RajaRupinderSingh You can add strings and store it to NSData. It's only sample code.